# Run-time Exception Fail to connect to camera Service in Some Devices

Tags: java, android, android-camera, barcode-scanner, android-vision

I am using Barcode Scanner in my app. In some mobile it is giving the run-time exception Fail to connect to camera.

Here is the code I am using for Camera

```
 /**
 * Opens the camera and applies the user settings.
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException if the method fails
 */
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private Camera createCamera() {
    int requestedCameraId = getIdForRequestedCamera(mFacing);
    if (requestedCameraId == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find requested camera.");
    }
    Camera camera = Camera.open(requestedCameraId);

    SizePair sizePair = selectSizePair(camera, mRequestedPreviewWidth, mRequestedPreviewHeight);
    if (sizePair == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find suitable preview size.");
    }
    Size pictureSize = sizePair.pictureSize();
    mPreviewSize = sizePair.previewSize();

    int[] previewFpsRange = selectPreviewFpsRange(camera, mRequestedFps);
    if (previewFpsRange == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find suitable preview frames per second range.");
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    if (pictureSize != null) {
        parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.getWidth(), pictureSize.getHeight());
    }

    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(
            previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MIN_INDEX],
            previewFpsRange[Camera.Parameters.PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX]);
    parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

    setRotation(camera, parameters, requestedCameraId);

    if (mFocusMode != null) {
        if (parameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(
                mFocusMode)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(mFocusMode);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera focus mode: " + mFocusMode + " is not supported on this device.");
        }
    }

    // setting mFocusMode to the one set in the params
    mFocusMode = parameters.getFocusMode();

    if (mFlashMode != null) {
        if (parameters.getSupportedFlashModes() != null) {
            if (parameters.getSupportedFlashModes().contains(
                    mFlashMode)) {
                parameters.setFlashMode(mFlashMode);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Camera flash mode: " + mFlashMode + " is not supported on this device.");
            }
        }
    }

    // setting mFlashMode to the one set in the params
    mFlashMode = parameters.getFlashMode();

    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    // Four frame buffers are needed for working with the camera:
    //
    //   one for the frame that is currently being executed upon in doing detection
    //   one for the next pending frame to process immediately upon completing detection
    //   two for the frames that the camera uses to populate future preview images
    camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new CameraPreviewCallback());
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(createPreviewBuffer(mPreviewSize));

    return camera;
}

   * Stops the camera.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mPreview != null) {
        mPreview.stop();
    }
}

/**
 * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, the associated detectors, and the
 * rest of the processing pipeline.
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPreview != null) {
        mPreview.release();
    }

}

    /**
 * Restarts the camera.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        startCameraSource();
}
```

The run time exception I am getting is

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:532)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:360)
```

Any help Regarding this issue because in some devices it is working but in some it is not working I am not able to get the issue.

Comment: In which OS version are you running app ?

Comment: I am using Android 6.0.1

Comment: Calling Camera.open() throws an exception if the camera is already in use by another application.

Comment: @FiXiT Did u add run time permission for access camera?

Comment: using this permission in menifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: No. If you are running your app on marshmallow then you need to use run time permission for access camera.  For more check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have also added run-time permission 
final int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            try {
                createCameraSource();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Always check if the camera is available or not before accesing it.

```
    private Camera mCamera;     
    /**
     * Opens the camera and applies the user settings.
     *
     * @throws RuntimeException if the method fails
     */
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private Camera createCamera() {
       int requestedCameraId = getIdForRequestedCamera(mFacing);
       if (requestedCameraId == -1) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Could not find requested camera.");
       }

       if (mCamera != null){
          mCamera.release();
          mCamera = null;
       }

       mCamera= Camera.open(requestedCameraId);

       if(camera == null){
          Toast.makeText(mContext, "Camera service is not available currently.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG.show())    
            }
           //....
       }
     }
```

And relsease the camera before `onDestroy()`.

```
/**
 * Releases the resources associated with the camera source, the associated detectors, and the
 * rest of the processing pipeline.
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPreview != null) {
        mPreview.release();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
}
```